# Use multiple copy of a drawn canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw with canvan somethink like this

[image]

For this I tried to draw a canvas arrow and want to use it multiple times, but with different position and text. How can I create this as a Object to use it several times?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var arrow = canvas.getContext("2d");
arrow.moveTo(0,0);
arrow.lineTo(175,0);
arrow.lineTo(200,50);
arrow.lineTo(175,100);
arrow.lineTo(0,100);
arrow.lineTo(25,50);
arrow.lineTo(0,0);
arrow.stroke();
arrow.fillStyle = "#333";
arrow.fill();

arrow.style.left = "100px";
arrow.style.top = "100px";
arrow.style.position = "absolute";

</script>
```

Has anyone a ideal how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do what K3N said, but i would go little performance-wise and prerender an image:

```
const arrow = document.createElement('canvas');
arrow.width: 100;
arrow.height: 100;

preRender();
function preRender() {
  const w = arrow.width;
  const h = arrow.height;
  ctx = arrow.getContext('2d');

  ctx.setTransform(1,0,1,1,0,0);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h * 0.5);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,-1,1,h,0);
  ctx.fillRect(0, h * 0.5, w, h * 0.5);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);         // resets transformations
}
```

and then you can just use it as image

```
ctx.drawImage(arrow,0,0,150,150);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

x and y position is left top

```
function drawArrow(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
    w = w || 200;
  h = h || 100;

  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w * 0.8, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + (h/2));
  ctx.lineTo(x + w * 0.8, y + h);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w * 0.2, y + (h/2));
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
  ctx.fill();``
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/jpbzb2v5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just embed the code into a function so you can pass different values as arguments. The arrow itself can be drawn using a skew transform combined with rectangles:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 1, 1, x, y);       // skew angle 1 (radians)
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h * 0.5);           // draw half arrow
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, -1, 1, x + h, y);  // skew opposite way, compensate for x
ctx.fillRect(0, h * 0.5, w, h * 0.5);     // second half
```

And if we wrap everything up as a function you can use it this way:

[image: result]

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#1F487C";

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  drawArrow(20 + i * 130, 50, 110, 50);  // draw arrow in a loop

function drawArrow(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,1,1,x,y);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h * 0.5);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,-1,1,x + h,y);
  ctx.fillRect(0, h * 0.5, w, h * 0.5);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);         // resets transformations
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600></canvas>
```

Tip: If you need increased performance simply replace `fillRect()` with `rect()` and use a `fill()` after the loop (remember `beginPath()` before the loop). This will invoke a single fill operation instead of multiple. However, they are in any case drawn well within the time of a single frame so there is really not much gain here though, with this or caching as an image first (unless you plan to draw hundreds+ of these at once).